# How to use Google Play Service in lower API Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development and tried the example of Google Map.The Google play service rev 29 and build target of my app is   Google API 16.But it shows the v21 error in res folder.After searched from google I had changed my both AVD target and application build target to Google API 23.But I couldn't start my AVD(even RAM 1907 and intel x86 system image) and laptop RAM is 8GB, shows 'android' forever. Finally, my questions are 
How to use Google Map in lower platforms and AVDs?(exactly in API 16)
Which google rev should I use apart from latest one in SDK manager?
I tried some answers but couldn't rectify my problems.Please help me to understand what actually possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**But I couldn't start my AVD(even RAM 1907 and intel x86 system image) and laptop RAM is 8GB, shows 'android' forever.**

This can be due to the high memory allocation of AVD (and your emulator configuration). AVD is really a memory-hog and other developers will suggest you use Genymotion or allocate less RAM (lets say 512/768 MB). Your development machine can also be a factor in here, if your machine has more memory and processing speed, AVD should load faster.

**Finally, my questions are How to use Google Map in lower platforms and AVDs?(exactly in API 16)**

The [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_6_connect_an_android_device) page in the Maps API documentation seems to require you have at least 4.4.2 version of Android. You can, however, check out [this tutorial](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/) that specifies an emulator using API level 16.

**Which google rev should I use apart from latest one in SDK manager?**

I don't see the issue of rev29 being used in this case. I think you can't downgrade the revision once you already updated it in the SDK Manager.

Comment: still I couldn't launch the AVD.The AVD was successfully launched in sometimes on my system.But whenever editing the AVD with different platforms and trying launch on same system it fails to launch and shows 'android'.